# TypeError: expressHandlebars is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

When using ***express-handlebars*** module,there encounter an error that saying,

```
app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({
                         ^

TypeError: expressHandlebars is not a function
```

My code is as follows

```
const express = require('express')
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const app = express()
// configure Handlebars view engine
app.engine('handlebars', expressHandlebars({
     defaultLayout: 'main',
}))
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
..........
```

I can't find any mistake in here because above code snippet is purely from book that I refer. But it doesn't seem to work.

I will be grateful if someone can to tell that is this because version different of ***express-handlebars*** between me and the book I refer or, Is there any mistake in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should require the express handlebars engine instead of the whole expressHandlebars package.

Change:

```
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars')
```

To:

```
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars').engine;
```

Comment: Thanks It works !

Comment: No problem!  Could you accept the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer